# How do I solve a SDE with two cases in R?

Tags: r, differential-equations, stochastic

I want to solve the following stochastic differential equation with R:

> \frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)+sigma*dW
>
> f(x)= a+bx+cx^2 (for x \leq 1) f(x)= a+bx (for x > 1)

and

> sigma=d^2

where (*a*, *b*, *c*, and *d* are constants).

I tried using:

```
f = expression(a+bx+cx^2)
s = expression(d^2)

solution <- sde.sim(X0=0.6, t0=0, N=2000, delta=0.01, drift = f, sigma = s )
```

But how do I include the second case (when x>1)?

Sorry for the poor inclusion of the mathematical expression. I do not how to write latex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this where  `(x <= 1)` would evaluate to 0 or 1 depending on the case.

```
f = expression(1+ 2 * x + (x <= 1) * 3*x^2)
s = expression(2^2)

solution <- sde.sim(X0=0.6, t0=0, N=2000, delta=0.01, drift = f, sigma = s)
```